# .NET 8 MAUI WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync results in NULL AccessToken

Tags: .net-core, maui, .net-8.0

We recently updated our application from .NET 7 to .NET 8, and our call to WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync results in the AccessToken property value being NULL.  This same code returned the appropriate access token in .NET 7:

```
    public static async Task<OAuthTokenResponse> Login()
    {
        try
        {
            WebAuthenticatorResult authResult = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(
            new Uri($"{_apiUrl}/auth"),
            new Uri("myscheme://"));

            OAuthTokenResponse response = new OAuthTokenResponse();

            if (authResult != null)
            {
                response.Success = true;
                response.AccessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
            }
            

            return response;              
        }
        catch
        {
            return new OAuthTokenResponse() { Success = false };
        }
    }
```

This does in fact match the (current) documentation for .NET 8 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=macios

What is interesting to me is that the authResult shows 2 parameters, one of which has a key of "?access_token" - is it not parsing correctly (i.e. is this a bug in WebAuthenticator)?  Also, if I look at the URI, it shows as `myscheme:///#?access_token=[tokenvalue]` - this seems to have an extra "/" character, even though manual testing in a browser is showing only two "/" characters in the resulting URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the project have any specific errors?

Comment: No exceptions are thrown, no.

Comment: Please provide more information：
What platform(s) is issue occurring on? 
Any other changes between .NET 7 app version and .NET 8? 
Any changes on auth service side? 
Where does flow break? Does browser window open asking for credentials (if expected)?

Comment: The issue occurs in both iOS and Android.

Comment: Yes, the browser window opens and you successfully log in, and a breakpoint right after the call to AuthenticateAsync() is hit.  The authResult.AccessToken value is null, BUT authResult.Properties has a property with Key = `?access_token`, which seems like a clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT Any additional information needed?

Comment: In the process of upgrading Xamarin to MAUI, is there any change in the code?

Comment: This wasn't an upgrade from Xamarin to Maui, but from .NET 7 to .NET 8

Comment: sorry, so is there any code changed?